# Some simulators disappeared in Xcode7

Tags: ios, xcode

In my project there is a list of simulators:

[image]

It is ok, but when I created another project there is limited number of simulators.

[image]

Why? How to fix this? I need there simulators for both: `iOS8` and `iOS9`.

Comment: Did you create your new project with XCode 7?

Comment: yes, I did it with Xcode 7

Comment: did you change your deployment target to something other than 9?

Comment: yes, to 8.4 deployment target

Comment: Did you try to add simulators in the device organiser?

Comment: ok, I solved the problem. I have no simulators for 8.4, but only for 8.3. On the list of simulators are the ones which are equal or newer than my deployment target:-) So, when I changed my deplyent target to 8.3 there are simulators for both: `8.3` and `9.0`.

Comment: yes. it just because you have only 8.3 available which is lower than your set deployment target (8.4).

Answer (score 0):

Remember about two important things:

- you have to install required simulators first:

[image]

As you can see there are installed simulators for `8.2` and `8.3`. It **doesnt mean** that they will appear in the list of simulators...

...because you have to remember about another important thing:

- your deployment target. It means that on the list of simulators will appear only that ones which are equal or newer from deployment target you set for **your app target** (*not for your project*).

[image]

In this case when I set target to `9.0` there will be following list of simulators:

[image]

The same is for `8.4` because I haven't downloaded simulators for `8.4`. But once I set deployment target to `8.3` or lower the list of simulators is following:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The list of devices that you see in the run destinations menu is the list of devices that the current target is compatible with.

Your new iOS app target likely has a deployment target version of 9.0, so all of the iOS 8.3 devices are not listed as available.

If you expect your app to run on older versions of iOS, you should update the deployment target (aka minimum supported version) in your project's build settings.